# Prevent Archiving In a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have asked this question on the [Jenkins mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/QapfvnlbDr0).

I have an upstream component, libraryA, I build, archive, and deploy via a Maven job, jobA. This works great. I have a downstream Maven job, jobB, that has a dependency on libraryA. This also works great, except…

I have a completely separate pipeline job, pipelineA specified by Jenkinsfile. Within that Jenkinsfile, I build a specific branch of libraryA I don’t want archived or deployed. In my Jenkinsfile I have “withMaven(mavenLocalRepo: ‘libraryA/.repository’, publisherStrategy: ‘EXPLICIT’)”, and inside that, “sh “””[…]mvn clean package sonar:sonar[…]””” (Any typos here are probably the fault of my typing here as I did not copy-paste. There are no errors from Jenkins when executing these steps.) I have also tried “options: [artifactsPublisher(disabled: true)]” in place of “publisherStrategy: ‘EXPLICIT’” and had the same results. I have verified when pipelineA builds libraryA, it does NOT get deployed to my remote Maven repository, and I expect it not to get deployed there. Good.

So, what happens?

Well, if I build pipelineA followed by jobB, jobB gets its copy of libraryA from pipelineA, causing the build to fail. If I then run jobA, jobB succeeds as expected.

I could change the version of libraryA in the branch pipelineA builds, but I’d rather not do that as it’s not correct for my particular use case. What else could I do? What did I miss? (I do not admin this Jenkins instance, so my access is limited in that respect.)

For clarity here is an approximation of the pipeline's Jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {

    environment {

        GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID = 'git_credential_name'

    }



    agent any

    tools {

        maven 'internal_maven'

        jdk 'openjdk'

        git 'internal_git'

    }

    stages {

        stage('Build Parent') {

            steps {

                checkoutRepos([[checkoutDir: 'parent', branch: 'gold', url: 'ssh://git@fake-git-url/parent.git']], env.GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID)

                withMaven(publisherStrategy: 'EXPLICIT') {

                    sh """

                        cd parent

                        mvn -U clean verify

                      """

                }

                stash name: 'parent', includes: 'pom.xml'

            }

        }

        stage('Build libraryParent') {

            steps {

                unstash 'parent'

                checkoutRepos([[checkoutDir: 'libraryParent', branch: 'gold', url: 'ssh://git@fake-git-url/libraryParent.git']], env.GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID)

                withMaven(mavenLocalRepo: 'libraryParent/.repository', publisherStrategy: 'EXPLICIT') {

                    sh """

                        mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=pom -Dfile=pom.xml -DpomFile=pom.xml

                        cd libraryParent

                        mvn clean verify -P jacoco sonar:sonar -U -Dsonar.host.url=https://fake-sonar-url -Dsonar.scm.provider=git

                       """

                }

                dir('libraryParent/libraryA/target/') {

                    stash name: 'libraryA', includes: 'libraryA-1000-SNAPSHOT.jar'

                }

            }

        }

        stage('Build appA') {

            steps {

                sonarAnApp 'appA'

            }

        }

        stage('Build appB') {

            steps {

                sonarAnApp 'appB'

            }

        }

        stage('Build appC') {

            steps {

                sonarAnApp 'appC'

            }

        }

    }

}



def sonarAnApp(final String appName) {

    unstash 'parent'

    unstash 'libraryA'

    checkoutRepos([[checkoutDir: appName, branch: 'gold', url: "ssh://git@fake-git-url/${appName}.git"]], env.GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID)

    withMaven(mavenLocalRepo: "$appName/.repository", publisherStrategy: 'EXPLICIT') {

        sh """

            mvn install:install-file -Dpackaging=pom -Dfile=pom.xml -DpomFile=pom.xml

            mvn install:install-file -Dfile=libraryA-1000-SNAPSHOT.jar

            cd $appName

            mvn clean verify -P jacoco sonar:sonar -U -Dsonar.host.url=https://fake-sonar-url -Dsonar.scm.provider=git

           """

    }
}
```

Comment: Its quiet confusing what you are trying to accomplish. But it sounds that you can use build trigger to trigger a different job withing your current job. If you can clearly explain what you are trying to do then we can help

Comment: I have a library I build in 2 separate jobs.

One is a simple Maven job. This one should to be archived. This works as expected.

The other is a pipeline that does a lot more stuff. It builds a specific branch of the library I don't want archived or accessible anywhere outside of the pipeline. In this pipeline I've tried building this library with a separate mavenLocalRepo and using publisherStrategy: 'EXPLICIT' or options: [artifactsPublisher(disabled: true)]. (This is the Jenkinsfile above.)

Unfortunately, the pipeline's version of the library is being archived.